# Play Star Wars in CMD with Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I know that the 2 commands I need to run are:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
Telnet Towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

I would like it to keep cmd open after running `Telnet Towel.blinkenlights.nl`.

This is what I have tried:

```
    Dim start As New Process()
    start.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    start.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c pkgmgr /iu:" & """" & "TelnetClient" & """"
    start.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    start.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    start.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    start.Start()
    System.WaitForExit()

    Dim playSW As New Process()
    playSW.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    playSW.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k Telnet Towel.blinkenlights.nl"
    playSW.Start()
    playSW.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Process's WaitForExit command to ensure a process is completed:

```
Dim start As New Process()
start.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
start.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c pkgmgr /iu:" & """" & "TelnetClient" & """"
start.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
start.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
start.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
start.Start()
start.WaitForExit()

Dim playSW As New Process()
playSW.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
playSW.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c Telnet Towel.blinkenlights.nl"
playSW.Start()
playSW.WaitForExit()
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you for your response, the only issue is that when it runs the second command, it is supposed to play a Star Wars clip but it does not and I am not sure why.

Comment: When running it using VB, it says Telnet is not an internal or external command but when using CMD normally, it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: add the workingdirectory property for where telnet is stored...do you have telnet installed?